# Google sheets sync to calendar

Tags: google-apps-script

``
Hi,
I have following script, but it doesn't sync multiple events (with different titles) with calendar  for one day, just rewrite the old event. Maybe someone can help? How can I fix it?
As far as I understand, I have to create an additional loop: if the name of the event does not match other names on a certain day, then the event should be created?

```
function sheet2calendar() {
 
  // Set up sheet and calendar
  var spreadsheet =SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('LIST OF ALL COMPANIES');
  var calendarID = spreadsheet.getRange("R1").getValue();
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarID);
 
  /* ... */
 
  var movies = spreadsheet.getRange("A2:o2004").getValues();
 
  for (x=0; x < movies.length; x++){

    // retrieve one entry at a time
    var entry = movies[x];

    // get start time from the 1st column, column 0
    var startTime = new Date(entry[8]);

   
    var eventLength = 24; // in hours
    var endTime = new Date(startTime.getTime() + eventLength*60*60*1000)

    // retrieve movie title
    var movie = entry[2]+' communication with client';
var description1 = entry [3]+" "+entry[14];
    /* ... */
   
    // ... within for loop
 
    // if movie name is missing/empty skip
    // this entry
    if (movie == ''){continue;}

    // get events during the start and end times
    // specified above
    var conflicts = calendar.getEvents(startTime, endTime);

    //  if the length of conflicts is 0, create an event directly
    if (conflicts.length == 0){
     createAllDayEvent(calendar, movie, startTime, endTime, {
          description: description1
        });
    }
    // if the length of conflict is larger than 0
    // iterate thorugh the conflicting events
    else {
      for (c=0; c < conflicts.length; c++){
        // load one conflict at a time
        var conflict = conflicts[c]

        // if title of conflict matches movie title
        // skip this conflicting event
        if (conflict.getTitle() == movie){continue;}
        // delete old event if the previous if
        // statement was not entered
        conflict.deleteEvent();  

        // create new event
        createAllDayEvent(calendar, movie, startTime, endTime,{
          description: description1
        });

      }
    }

  }
 
}
 
function createAllDayEvent(cal, title, start, end,{
          description }){
  // create event with provided title, start
  // start and end time
  var event = cal.createEvent(title, start, end,{
          description
        });

 

}
 

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Sync to Calendar')
      .addItem('Sync Now',
               'sheet2calendar') // <-- name of our function
      .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you clarify your goal? Your script currently checks for event conflicts based on a timeframe defined on Spreadsheet cells, then if there are conflicts, it manually deletes the event and creates a new one. Based on the comments, it seems intended. Please provide a [minimal reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as well as describe what have you tried already and which issue you’ve ran into.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately it's delete all events on this date. In case I have one event with title "A" and want to add another event with title "B" on one day, script delete event A and create event B, but I need two events A and B in my calendar. Unfortunately I don't know how I can fix this script.

Comment: Well, in your script you use a period of time to fetch events to determine if an event is a conflict. Additionally you are skipping the event creation when the “movie title” is a match. By the comments above, this feels intended. See `if (conflict.getTitle() == movie){continue;}` and the lines above. I’d recommend changing this logic as a start point.